# php-login choose page after login

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

I am using the minimal version of php-login from:  http://www.php-login.net/  on Windows 7.  When the user logs in, the login is verified and the response from the verification is True or False. The response is returned to index.php which has this code

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
include("views/logged_in.php");
```

I would like to give the user an opportunity to choose which page they go to after logging in but that page can only be accessible when the user is logged in. Any ideas?  Let me know if you need more information or if what I am trying to do isn't clear.  Thanks

======= UPDATED BELOW =========================
I modified the code below so that if the user login validation returns true, the user is directed to a page that has these two links  `<a href="views/logged_in_green.php">Green</a>` `<a href="views/logged_in_blue.php">Blue</a>`  when the user clicks a link the user gets an Access Forbidden error message.

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    include("views/choose-pages.htm");
} else {
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

Comment: Include another page, not logged_in.php, or redesign the logged_in.php, where user has a form, and it can select where to jump. Process that, and redirect.

Comment: `if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {` already makes sure of that. Include other pages or make some `hrefs`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the basic process of how the "include" page gets restricted, well, I understand how that page has restricted access, but if I present a form with links to other pages and I present the logged-in user with an array of links to various pages, for example, show links to blue.php and green.php those two php page would not be restricted to logged in users only because they are not passed through the login validation. At least that is they way it seems to work as far as I understand the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify not_logged_in.php and have 2 submit buttons like Google, normal "Google search" and  "I'm feeling luckey".

```
 <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in green" />
 <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in blue" />
```

then modify index.php

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {

if ($_POST["login"] == "Log in green") {
include("green.php");
} else {
include("blue.php");
}

}
```

Comment: I like this approach, I have the "true" response from the login validation, but where do I get the ($_POST["login"] response from? Is there someway to get more than just True / False from the login validation?  I could use separate login pages like, login-green.php and login-blue.php and put a variable or something in that page, but, I don't know how to pass that along with the True / False.

Comment: Just make 2 submit buttons with same name and different value in not_logged_in.php or your custom log in form page.

Comment: I tried that, when the user logs in it goes to the validation and that returns "true" to index.php. Even through they are different buttons the result that is returned is "true", for example, it doesn't return "true-green" which could be used to determine which button was clicked. It only returns the response that the login was valid.  Maybe php-login cannot be modified for this purpose. Maybe I need to use a different user registration and login script?

Comment: Works fine on http://phptesting.orgfree.com/index.php log in with Username test and password 123456

Comment: Thank You very much for the excellent example. Sorry about the delay in responding. I just made the changes that you recommended and it working perfectly. I really, really appreciate your help and advice and your persistence in help me understand this. Thank you for making the example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to create a main page (main.php), in this page write the code of choosing a page, its easy !!

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
include("views/main.php");
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but my understanding is that if I include views/main.php and that page has links to green.php and blue.php  those two php pages will be accessible whether or not the user is logged in?  main.php is only accessible to a user that is logged in, but the pages linked from main.php would not be possible to restrict access?  Is that correct?

Comment: Take it easy folk, user cannot access to any page without logging in correctly !!

Answer (score 0):

You could store your pages names/links in mysql database first and then get the pages links/names from the mysql database in an array and put it right after your code which would excute after the users are logged in. like so:

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
///Your array of pages here ///
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you can do this:

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == false) {
header(location someotherpage.php)
```

You could put that code in the blue.php, green.php etc etc

Second edit:

I hope i understand it correctly and if so, then you can use something like this:

```
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == false) {
echo "access denied";
```

you could even populate your page names and links in a drop down menu fashion so the users can select one and go to that page.

Comment: If I present the logged-in user with an array of links to various pages, for example, show links to blue.php and green.php   those two php page would not be restricted to logged in users only because they are not passed through the login validation. At least that is they way it seems to work as far as I understand the process.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. The code below would be useful is I wanted a user who is not logged in to go to a specific page. However, I still need to give the user who is logged in a way to choose which page.  I tried:   include("views/choose-pages.htm");     and when the logged-in user clicks a link on choose-pages.htm they get an "Access Forbidden" error message.

 if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == false) {
header(location someotherpage.php)